Is there a formal term for "buddy taping"?
https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/selfcare-instructions/broken-toe-self-care:

Buddy taping: Wrap tape around the injured toe and the toe next to it. This helps keep your toe stable. Place a small wad of cotton between your toes to prevent tissues.

Is there a more formal term than "buddy taping"?


(Image source)

USA English: neighbor strapping; British English: neighbour strapping. Alternatively, 'taping' in each case.

A special appliance called a Bedford Splint can be used for fingers, but the phrase 'Bedford splinting' seems very rare.

And that's only "more formal" if you consider "neighbor" more formal than "buddy" which, in this context, I do not, as they are both metaphorical, not descriptive or analytical.  You don't want something more "formal", you want something more scientific or anatomic.

This would be better asked on english.stackexchange.com, IMO.

Mount Sinai is a renowned hospital. If they label it buddy taping, isn't that enough?

@TimR - I would regard 'neighbour' as 'descriptive' - "3. COUNTABLE NOUN You can refer to something which stands next to something else of the same kind as  its neighbour. Each house was packed close behind its neighbour" Collins Dictionary. I would see 'each house was packed close behind its buddy' as informal verging n infantile.

The adjacent toe is acting as a splint.

@YosefBaskin University College Hospital in London is pretty renowned also, and they call it 'neighbour finger strapping' in a patient information leaflet.

Perhaps "amici ligans"  would be a suitably latinate expression

@MichaelHarvey But these are toes, not houses.

This wikipedia article will put the name in a cultural context:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_system

It appears in the UK/NHS  it's called "buddy strapping" https://www.royalberkshire.nhs.uk/media/bdqfqiex/buddy-strapping-discharge-advice_mar24.pdf and @TimR the finger next to the injured is referred to as its neighbour … treated with neighbour strapping for 1 week and “… the finger may be taped to the one next to it this is called buddy or neighbour strapping.”
